# Leverage browser caching

Tags: apache, .htaccess, caching

I have a website and when I check page speed with Google plug-in, I receive:

Leverage browser caching
The following resources are missing a cache expiration

Where can I change the settings for this?

Comment: what is your platform? (IIS, Apache, etc....)? What type of file is it referring to?

Comment: umm? I blog with wordpress and godaddy. I want to say Apache.

Answer (score 15):

Edit `.htaccess` and append

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
</IfModule>
```

This link can help you:
http://www.quickonlinetips.com/archives/2010/05/leverage-browser-caching-increase-website-speed/

Answer (score 2):

**Leverage Browser Caching**

Reduce the load times of pages by storing commonly used files from your website on your visitors browser.

To enable browser caching you need to edit your HTTP headers to set expiry dates on certain types of files.

Find your .htaccess file in the root of your domain, this file is a hidden file but should show up in FTP clients like FileZilla or CORE. You can edit the htaccess file with notepad or any form of basic text editor.

In this file we will set our caching parameters to tell the browser what types of files to cache.

The code below tells browsers what to cache and how long to "remember" it. It should be added to the top of your .htaccess file.

```
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
&lt;IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 days"
&lt;IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

**Recommendations:**

- Be aggressive with your caching for all static resources
- Expiry at a minimum of one month
- Don't set your caching more than a year in advance!

Reference: http://websitespeedoptimizations.com/LeverageBrowserCaching.aspx

Comment: Just to let you know the url isn't valid anymore . I'm reading here now https://varvy.com/pagespeed/leverage-browser-caching.html

Answer (score 0):

A better approach to [leverage browser cache](https://wpbloghelp.com/setup-wordpress-leverage-browser-caching/) is to use the *.htaccess* file with the `FILEMATCH` directives. Here is the quick code you can put into your *.htaccess* inside your website. This is a quick fix and does not require further changes until you have some other concerns.

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
   ExpiresActive On
   ExpiresDefault A0
   <FilesMatch "\.(txt|xml|js)$">
   ExpiresDefault A691200
   </FilesMatch>
   <FilesMatch "\.(css)$">
   ExpiresDefault A691200
   </FilesMatch>
   <FilesMatch "\.(flv|ico|pdf|avi|mov|ppt|doc|mp3|wmv|wav|mp4|m4v|ogg|webm|aac)$">
   ExpiresDefault A691200
   </FilesMatch>
   <FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf|webp)$">
   ExpiresDefault A691200
   </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
   <FilesMatch "\.(txt|xml|js)$">
   Header set Cache-Control "max-age=691200"
   </FilesMatch>
   <FilesMatch "\.(css)$">
   Header set Cache-Control "max-age=691200"
   </FilesMatch>
   <FilesMatch "\.(flv|ico|pdf|avi|mov|ppt|doc|mp3|wmv|wav|mp4|m4v|ogg|webm|aac)$">
   Header set Cache-Control "max-age=691200"
   </FilesMatch>
   <FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf|webp)$">
   Header set Cache-Control "max-age=691200"
   </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```