# How to get my site to cache javascript files for a certain period of time?

Tags: javascript, html, caching

I have on my page this

`<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />` and I noticed that my javascript file is not being cached. Everytime I reload the page, it downloads again with a status of `200`. I want it to keep it cached for a period of time like an hour, so when I refresh the page, it should not download the js file, and should get a status of 304 (no change).

Does anyone know what the above tag means exactly and how I should change it?

Thanks

EDIT:

It seems in IE11 (rendering mode IE10) it shows status 200, but in chrome 49, it shows 304. However I want it to cache in IE.

Comment: Have you tried caching your data in localstorage???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Leverage browser caching](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634172/leverage-browser-caching)

Comment: This is microsoft IIS, also I don't have access to the IIS software. I can only change the html file. Also how would you cache a JS file in local storage?

Answer (score 0):

In web.config add to `configuration section:

```
<caching>
  <profiles>
    <add extension=".css" policy="CacheForTimePeriod" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" duration="00:00:30" />
    <add extension=".jpg" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" />
    <add extension=".js" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" />
  </profiles>
</caching>
```

Comment: Putting that crashes the server.

Comment: To the file named `web.config` in the root of the server.