# Leveraging browser cache in boilerplate

Tags: .htaccess, caching, frontend, pagespeed, html5boilerplate

I've used a boilerplate to create a website and I've tested it on https://testmysite.thinkwithgoogle.com/ and it said I have to leverage my browser cache. After doing some research, it says I have to add [this tweak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634172/leverage-browser-caching) in .htaccess. The issue is that this tweak already exist in boilerplate .htaccess so I'm not really sure why the speed checker said I should be leveraging my browser cache?

Any insights why it gives this error?

**Update:** I've tested it on gtmetrix, it says I have to leverage browser cache of bunch of img, js, and css files. I've checked .htaccess files and there the expires tag of all the mentioned above files. Still no clue why it keep giving that note?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing extensive research, I found that git hub web pages don't allow for server configuration, so using .htaccess wouldn't leverage my browser cache. Hoping that github would solve this issue.

Comment: You could use Cloudflare.com (which has many performance improvements) with GitHub pages